# R aggregating values in DF1 by intervals in DF2

Tags: r, aggregate

Given `DF1$Ages`, how do I aggregate it to list the number of rows within intervals defined by `DF2$Ages`?

For example, I would like to generate `out1` from `DF1`, using intervals defined by `DF2$Ages`.

```
DF1 <- data.frame("Ages"=c(1,2,4,8,11,13,15,16))
DF1
#    Ages
#  1    1
#  2    2
#  3    4
#  4    8
#  5   11
#  6   13
#  7   15
#  8   16

DF2 <- data.frame("Ages" = c(3, 5, 9, 11, 12, 17), 
                  "Type" = c("N", "R", "N", "R", "N", "R"))
#   Ages Type
# 1    3    N
# 2    5    R
# 3    9    N
# 4   11    R
# 5   12    N
# 6   17    R

out1 <- data.frame("Counts"=c(2,1,1,1,0,3))
out1
#   Counts
# 1      2
# 2      1
# 3      1
# 4      1
# 5      0
# 6      3
```

That is,

- `2` values in `DF1` that fall in the range `(0,3]` from `DF2$Ages`,
- `1` value in `DF1` that fall in the range `(3,5]` from `DF2$Ages`,
- `1` value in `DF1` that fall in the range `(5,9]` from `DF2$Ages`,
- `1` value in `DF1` that fall in the range `(9,11]` from `DF2$Ages`,
- `0` values in `DF1` that fall in the range `(11,12]` from `DF2$Ages`, and
- `3` values in `DF1` that fall in the range `(12,17]` from `DF2$Ages`.

Comment: A basic `cut` operation does it - `table(cut(DF1$Ages, c(0,DF2$Ages)))`